# makefile cuts off variable passed to rule

Tags: makefile

Below is a simplified version of two rules in one of my makefiles.

```
Link:
    ld $(SONG_OBJ) -o Songs/$(FILE)/$(FILE)

Song:
    $(eval SONG_OBJ = $(wildcard Songs/$(FILE)/Build/*.o))
    make Link FILE=$(FILE) SONG_OBJ=$(SONG_OBJ)
```

As such the SONG_OBJ contains several strings separated by whitespace. However, it appears that the Song rule only sends the first string, i.e. it cuts off anything in SONG_OBJ after the first whitespace, to the Link rule. Any advice on how to fix this problem? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You need double quotes around `SONG_OBJ=$(SONG_OBJ)` in the recursive invocation of `make`:

```
    make Link FILE=$(FILE) SONG_OBJ="$(SONG_OBJ)"
```

As it stands, `SONG_OBJ` is set to the first word, and the other names are simply passed to `make` as more targets to be built (in addition to `Link`).